# Mimic a temporary view for Neo4j results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that consists of various pieces of evidence. I want to aggregate the confidence score between evidence between two nodes on the fly and return a new triple like `node1-[aggregate_score {agg_confidence:100}]->node2`.

My current query:

```
MATCH (n1{name:"test_node1"})-[:IS_SRC_OF_EVIDENCE]->(test_ev:TestEvidence {theme:"test_rel"})<-[:IS_TRG_OF_EVIDENCE]-(n2{name:"test_node2"})
WITH avg(test_ev.confidence) as agg_confidence, n1, n2
CREATE (n1)-[statement:TEST_REL{confidence:agg_confidence}]->(n2)
RETURN (n1)-[statement]->(n2)
```

From what I understand, there is no way to return a temporary relationships - only things that exist can be returned. So the next best bet would be to have something like a sub-graph that I could temporarily store this new relationship in; acting as a cache of sorts that I could regularly clear.

Before someone asserts that I should explicitly create this aggregate relationship for all sets of nodes, this is not an option as there are several metadata fields that will be filtered on that are not listed - date_published etc. which would then impact the aggregate score.

Any recommendations or has any one worked through a similar use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use APOC to create [virtual nodes & relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/virtual/virtual-nodes-rels/#virtual-nodes-rels), which the neo4j Browser can visualize but which do not actually exist in the DB.

For example, running this query in the neo4j Browser should show virtual `TEST_REL` relationships with the desired `confidence` values:

```
MATCH (n1{name:"test_node1"})-[:IS_SRC_OF_EVIDENCE]->(t:TestEvidence {theme:"test_rel"})<-[:IS_TRG_OF_EVIDENCE]-(n2{name:"test_node2"})
RETURN n1, n2,
  apoc.create.vRelationship(n1, 'TEST_REL', {confidence: AVG(t.confidence)}, n2) as rel
```